# Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to follow the Udacity Developing Android Apps course. I got to Lesson 3.03. Here, we are instructed to launch a new Activity (`DetailActivity`) from `ForecastFragment` when clicking an item in a list.

However, I keep getting an error when attempting to launch the `DetailActivity`. `Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment`, where it's caused by `DetailActivity.java` in it's `onCreate()` method.

I've already searched around, but none of the fixes suggested for this issue helped me at all.

The specific error is:

```
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class
com.myapp.sunshine.app.DetailActivityFragment that is not a Fragment
```

**DetailActivity.java**

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail); //failing here
    }
}
```

**DetailActivityFragment.java**

```
public class DetailActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
    }
 }
```

**activity_detail.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.sunshine.app.DetailActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I should mention that I'm *not* using support libraries--as I'm targeting SDK 21+, Lollipop only.

This isn't the only fragment we've created in the course either. The other fragment we created looks identical to this one.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.sunshine.app.ForecastFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And for good measure, I'm including the `ForecastFragment` class. I've omitted unnecessary parts of code.

**ForecastFragment.java**

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecaseAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 74/58",
                "Sunday - Rainy - 65/59",
                "Monday - Cloudy - 72/67"
        };
        final List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        mForecaseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                weekForecast);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecaseAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String forecast = mForecaseAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent detailActivityIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
                startActivity(detailActivityIntent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**fragment_detail.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".DetailActivityFragment">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

which is nearly identical to

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_forecast"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you post fragment_detail.xml?

Comment: Updated the OP with `fragment_detail.xml` and `fragment_main.xml` @Blackbelt

Comment: @Blackbelt Nope--just the one `DetailActivityFragment.java`

Comment: @Blackbelt Why would deleting that line fix it? I'm not saying it won't, but I don't understand how that line is in the `fragment_main.xml` and it still works fine.

Comment: can you try cleaning up the project and run it again ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Cleaning the project and deleting the line `tools:context=".DetailActivityFragment"` did nothing. Same errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`

```
public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail); //failing here
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, and it still didn't work. Furthermore, the Android course is actually using `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: ok so you must use the support library! https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html post the imports that are you using.

Comment: That fixed it! How come Android Studio doesn't autopopulate that when generating a new Activity with fragment? Also, why didn't I have to extend `FragmentActivity` in the `MainActivity`? (`MainActivity` extends `Activity`)

Comment: hehe, if you choose to use fragments you have to change to FragmentActivity  manually.

Comment: but why didn't I have to do it for the `MainActivity`?